# string passing error using json.decode in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, parsing, dart

I'm saving a string of this format `"[{text: drding4disruption.com, quantity:10.0}, {text: google.com, quantity:6.0}]"`

so reading some tutorials I got to know that we can use `json.convert` method to parse  a string but here i'm getting

I did try to use `json.decode(the_string);` but It shows this error

```
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 3)
E/flutter (14216): [{text: 4 medium size potatoes (boiled, peeled), quantity: 4.0, measure: <u...
E/flutter (14216):   ^
E/flutter (14216):
```

how do I parse it so that I can access the map as well

Answer (score 1):

Save the string in this format by adding double quote to fields and string values :

```json
[
   {
      "text":"drding4disruption.com",
      "quantity":10
   },
   {
      "text":"google.com",
      "quantity":6
   }
]
```

Finally decode it:  `json.decode(the_string);`

To consume it as `YAML syntax` take a look to [this `yaml` package](https://pub.dev/packages/yaml)

Comment: thanks for answering but I can't do this because I'm the string from a api request or is there a way can I do it?

Comment: thats a third part API also I'm able to parse the data that API returns which also dosen't contains any double quotes for the keys and the child

Comment: In order to be able to parse data returned by your API request as JSON, the string must be in the above format!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `import 'dart:convert'` library and do it as following: 
From JSON list to String

```
final String listAsString = jsonEncode(list);
```

From String to JSON list, simply reverse

```
final List list = jsonDecode(listAsString);
```

**Make sure your JSON map keys and values are quoted like this**

```
var list = [{"text": "drding4disruption.com", "quantity":10.0}, {"text": "google.com", "quantity":6.0}];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, lemme save the string by encoding, maybe it can decode in that format as it was encoded